# Where to start: what set of N letters makes the most words?

Tags: algorithm

I'm having trouble coming up with a non-brute force approach to solve this problem I've been wondering: what set of N letters can be used to make the most words from a given dictionary? Letters can be used any number of times.

For example, for N=3, we can have EST to give words like TEST and SEE, etc...

Searching online, I found some answers (such as listed above for EST), but no description of the approach.

My question is: what well-known problems are similar to this, or what principles should I use to tackle this problem?

NOTE: I know it's not necessarily true that if EST is the best for N=3, then ESTx is the best for N=4. That is to say, you can't just append a letter to the previous solution.

In case you're wondering, this question came to mind because I was wondering what set of 4 ingredients could make the most cocktails, and I started searching for that. Then I realized my question was specific, and so I figured this letter question is the same type of problem, and started searching for it as well.

Comment: Solving your cocktail problem is significantly simpler, for example, duplication (the "EE" in "sEE"...) didn't exist, the universe is very small (I guess less than a few thousand), and the input is specific (set of ingredients) vs. the goal to find the set given its size. That's not to say the question is invalid though.

Comment: I'm not sure where to start, but I suspect it is with the dictionary, not with sets of letters. Find the right dictionary representation and the question probably becomes a trivial lookup for each N.

Comment: For the general case with N words, each of which can use any subset of the M available letters, this is unfortunately NP-hard.  See my proof here: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/64334/n-songs-m-instruments-how-to-pick-k-instruments-to-cover-maximal-amount-of-son/64348#64348 ("instruments" = letters, "songs" = words).  (Note that we lose nothing by forgetting the order and multiplicity of the letters in a word.)

Comment: @mrmcgreg: In order for a word to be "enabled" by some set of available letters, the only information we care about is the unordered set of letters it uses.  (So e.g. a first step in any algorithm would be to normalise a word to this unordered set of used letters.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

For each word in dictionary, sort it letters and remove duplicates. Let it be the *skeleton* of the word. For each skeleton, count how many words contain it.  Let it be its *frequency*.  Ignore all skeletons whose size is higher than N.

Let a *subskeleton* be any possible removals of 1 or more letters from the skeleton, i.e. EST has subskeletons of E,S,T,ES,ET,ST.  For each skeleton of size N, add the count of this skeleton and all its subskeletons. Select the skeleton with maximal sum.

You need O(2**N*D) operations, where D is size of the dictionary.

Correction: we need to take into account all skeletons of size up to N (not only of words), and the numbet of operations will be O(2**N*C(L,N)), where L is the number of letters (maybe 26 in english).

Comment: "Select the skeleton with maximum sum" -- if you only consider the skeletons *of words*, you can miss the optimal solution. Example: words are AB, BC, CD and n=3. An optimal solution is ABC, but this will not be found by your algorithm.

Comment: Looks better.  But IIUC, O(2\*\*N\*C(L,N)) is actually the *number* of skeletons that you will consider -- in that case, solving the problem in the same time complexity implies O(1) time per skeleton.  I think this is achievable by enumerating  the 2^N subskeletons of any given starting skeleton in Gray code order, but you should be explicit about this.

Comment: "I think this is achievable by enumerating the 2^N subskeletons of any given starting skeleton in Gray code order, but you should be explicit about this." - they should know it themselves.  It is not a rocket science.

Comment: Your overall solution is obvious; using Gray codes to speed it up is the least obvious part of it.

Answer (score 0):

So I coded up a solution to this problem that uses a hash table to get things done. I had to deal with a few problems along the way too!

1. Let `N` be the size of the group of letters you are looking for that can make the most words. Let `L` be the length of the dictionary.
2. Convert each word in the dictionary into a set of letters: `'test' -> {'e','s','t'}`
3. For each number 1 to N inclusive, create a cut list that contains the words you can make with *exactly* that many letters.
4. Make a hash table for each number 1 to N inclusive, then go through the corresponding cut list and use the set as a key, and increment by 1 for each member of the cut list.
5. This was the part that gave me trouble! Create a set out of your cut list (unique_cut_list) for N. This is essentially all the populated key-value pairs for the hash table for N.
6. For each set in unique_cut_list, generate all subsets, and check the corresponding hash table (the size of the subset) to see if there is a value. If there is, add that value to the hash table for N with the key of the original set.
7. Finally, go through the hash table and find the max value. The corresponding key is the group of letters you're after.

You go through the dictionary 1+2N times for steps 1-5, step 6 goes through a version of the dictionary and check (2^N)-1 subsets each time (ignore null set). That gives O(2NL + L*2^N) which should approach O(L*2^N). Not bad, since N will not be too big in most applications!

Comment: It looks like you only consider letter sets that are a subset of some word.  So e.g., if words are AB, BC and n=3, you will miss the optimal set ABC.  (Though you would get it if e.g. ABCD or ABC itself happened to also be words.)

Comment: If you fix this by generating all (A choose N) size-N sets (for an A-letter alphabet), and if N is around A/2, the resulting time complexity will be nearly doubly exponential.  There is a singly exponential solution involving starting with the smallest sets, generating each superset *that contains exactly one more letter*, and then adding the current set's weight to the value corresponding to that superset to the hashtable (creating a new key for the superset if necessary).